# Generating output by time interval where there are no values in source

Tags: logparser

I have a message log file that contains one line per message sent, with a timestamp rounded to the minute. I can use Logparser to generate a report on the message frequency per minute and output a chart showing the same. Here's the query I'm using to produce the report:

```
SELECT  
    QUANTIZE (Date, 60) AS M, 
    COUNT(*) AS Total 
FROM '[LOGFILEPATH]' 
GROUP BY M 
ORDER BY M
```

This is great for showing the message traffic rate for those minutes *when traffic has been generated*.

However, I would like to output a chart that also shows the minute intervals where the message count is **0** - in a bar chart, the bar would be at 0 for that minute. This will show us intervals when there has been no message traffic.

Naturally, this isn't in the source data, because it's not logging "no message". Any ideas how to do this? I actually don't care if it's Logparser - Powershell is something else I'm happy to use. Or even Excel, although I highly prefer a solution that can be scripted without manual intervention.

We're a Windows shop with limited access to dev tools, so no Python, bash, etc solutions, please.

Here's some sample (real, obfuscated) data that contanis a nearly half-hour interval where there is no traffic being logged.

```
Date,MID,Host,Sender,Recipient,Subject,Last State
2017-10-26 01:56,1078941,smtp3 (10.0.0.156),bounces@example.com,2.O@d.com.au,Notification has been created successfully,Message 1078941 to 2.O@d.com.au received remote SMTP response 'ok'
2017-10-26 01:56,1078938,smtp3 (10.0.0.156),bounces@example.com,a@y.com.au,Notification has been created successfully,Message 1078940 to bounces@example.com received remote SMTP response '2.0.0'
2017-10-26 01:55,4571113,smtp1 (10.0.1.59),bounces@example.com,K@c.com,Notification has been created successfully,Message 4571113 to K@c.com received remote SMTP response '2.0.0'
2017-10-26 01:55,1078936,smtp3 (10.0.0.156),bounces@example.com,G.F@y.com.au,Notification has been created successfully,Message 1078936 to G.F@y.com.au received remote SMTP response 'ok'
2017-10-26 01:54,4571083,smtp1 (10.0.1.59),bounces@example.com,B.H@b.com,Notification has been created successfully,Message 4571083 to B.H@b.com received remote SMTP response 'Mail accepted'.
2017-10-26 01:53,1078927,smtp3 (10.0.0.156),bounces@example.com,S.R@g.com,Notification has been created successfully,Message 1078927 to S.R@g.com received remote SMTP response '2.0.0'
2017-10-26 01:52,4571051,smtp1 (10.0.1.59),bounces@example.com,A.U@r.com.au,Notification has been created successfully,Message 4571051 to A.U@r.com.au received remote SMTP response 'ok'
2017-10-26 01:23,4570598,smtp1 (10.0.1.59),bounces@example.com,T@h.com,Notification has been created successfully,Message 4570598 to T@h.com received remote SMTP response '2.0.0'
2017-10-26 01:23,4570594,smtp1 (10.0.1.59),bounces@example.com,I@k.com.au,Notification has been created successfully,Message 4570594 to I@k.com.au received remote SMTP response 'ok'
2017-10-26 01:22,4570579,smtp1 (10.0.1.59),bounces@example.com,I.C@s.com.au,Notification has been created successfully,Message 4570579 to I.C@s.com.au received remote SMTP response '2.0.0'
2017-10-26 01:22,4570577,smtp1 (10.0.1.59),bounces@example.com,P.M@h.net.au,Notification has been created successfully,Message 4570577 to P.M@h.net.au received remote SMTP response '2.0.0'
2017-10-26 01:22,4570575,smtp1 (10.0.1.59),bounces@example.com,O@h.com.au,Notification has been created successfully,Message 4570575 to O@h.com.au received remote SMTP response '2.0.0'
2017-10-26 01:21,4570571,smtp1 (10.0.1.59),bounces@example.com,O@f.com,Notification has been created successfully,Message 4570571 to O@f.com received remote SMTP response 'ok'
2017-10-26 01:21,4570557,smtp1 (10.0.1.59),bounces@example.com,O.M@m.v.edu.au,Notification has been created successfully,Message 4570557 to O.M@m.v.edu.au received remote SMTP response 'OK'
2017-10-26 01:21,4570549,smtp1 (10.0.1.59),bounces@example.com,A@a.com,Notification has been created successfully,Message 4570550 to bounces@example.com received remote SMTP response '2.0.0'
2017-10-26 01:20,1078803,smtp3 (10.0.0.156),bounces@example.com,M.1@l.com.au,Notification has been created successfully,Message 1078803 to M.1@l.com.au received remote SMTP response '2.0.0'
2017-10-26 01:20,1078802,smtp3 (10.0.0.156),bounces@example.com,B@g.com,New Account,Message 1078802 to B@g.com received remote SMTP response '2.0.0'
2017-10-26 01:20,4570539,smtp1 (10.0.1.59),bounces@example.com,I@v.com.au,Notification has been created successfully,Message 4570539 to I@v.com.au received remote SMTP response 'OK'
2017-10-26 01:19,1078794,smtp3 (10.0.0.156),bounces@example.com,A.T@b.com,Notification has been created successfully,Message 1078794 to A.T@b.com received remote SMTP response 'ok'
```

Comment: Yes, that's actually impossible to do with one single query, because as you correctly stated, there are no input records in the time periods you are looking for. You could use a two-step approach: the first step aggregates by the minute as you do now and produces a CSV file, while the second step queries that CSV file together with another CSV file, artificially produced with the same format and one dummy record for each minute in a day. Querying both and aggregating again by the minute - and adjusting counts to reflect the dummy entry - should allow you to obtain the output you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments it would be a multi step process starting with getting the dates covered in your log file:

```
SELECT MIN(Date) AS MinDate, MAX(Date) as MaxDate 
INTO theDates.csv 
FROM yourlog.log
```

The reading in the dates contained in *theDates.csv* using say a Powershell program to generate a log file that matched your log format and contained exactly 1 record per minute.

Then you can run your original query with a slight tweak:

```
SELECT 
   QUANTIZE(Date, 60) as M,
   SUB(COUNT(*), 1) as total
FROM yourlog.log, yourfakelogfile.log
ORDER BY M
GROUP BY M
```

The slight tweaking being the count is being decremented by 1 so that you get zeros in the time period where there was no activity.

Put all three of these steps in say a powershell script and you have an automated, repeatable process.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to avoid creating a dummy file with just "1" per time interval, and subtracting it later, but that might just have to be the way to go.